# VariableDeclaratorID expected after this token. On myMediaList.add(myBook); (myMovies;) (myGames;)

Tags: java

I'm getting a series of errors I cannot figure out.

```
Syntax Error on token "myBook", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token.

Syntax Error on token "myMovie", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token.

Syntax Error on token "myGame", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token.
```

Code snippet follows:

```
package src.edu.htc.java1.library;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * 
 */


/**
 * This class is used to test our library and media classes.
 *
 */
public class MediaTester {

    /**
     * This is the main test method
     * @param args - values passed in by the JVM when running
     * the application
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Book myBook = new Book();
        myBook.setLibraryId(123456L);
        myBook.setLocation("Eden Prairie");
        myBook.setTitle("My Book Title");
        ArrayList<String> authorList = new ArrayList<String>();
        authorList.add("Joe Author");
        authorList.add("Jane Author");
        myBook.setAuthors(authorList);
        myBook.setCopyright("1984");
        myBook.setFormat("paperback");
        myBook.setNumberOfPages(385);
        myBook.setPublishers("Some Publisher");

        System.out.println(myBook);

        Movies myMovie = new Movies();
        myMovie.setTitle("Fargo");
        myMovie.setReleaseDate(2123);
        myMovie.setDirector("Jie Wu");
        myMovie.setActors("Jessie");
        myMovie.setMPAA_rating("R");
        ArrayList<String> actors = new ArrayList<String>();
        actors.add("Tom Hanks");


        System.out.println(myMovie);


        Games myGames = new Games();
        myGames.setTitle("Starcraft");
        myGames.setConsoleType("wii");
        myGames.setEsbnRatings("E");
        myGames.setReleaseDate("2012");
        myGames.setPublishers("Blizzard");

        System.out.println(myGames);
        }
    ArrayList<Media> myMediaList = new ArrayList<Media>();
    myMediaList.add(myBook);
    myMediaList.add(myMovie);
    myMediaList.add(myGame);
    Library myLibrary = new Library();

    for (Media item : myMediaList) {
    myLibrary.addToCollection(item);
    System.out.println(item);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: If my answer accurately solves your issue, please mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra bracket misplacing all of your code outside of the designated block. Try this:

*Notice that I just removed the bracket under:

```
System.out.println(item);
}
```

---

```
package src.edu.htc.java1.library;
import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * This class is used to test our library and media classes.
     *
     */
    public class MediaTester {

        /**
         * This is the main test method
         * @param args - values passed in by the JVM when running
         * the application
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {



            Book myBook = new Book();
            myBook.setLibraryId(123456L);
            myBook.setLocation("Eden Prairie");
            myBook.setTitle("My Book Title");
            ArrayList<String> authorList = new ArrayList<String>();
            authorList.add("Joe Author");
            authorList.add("Jane Author");
            myBook.setAuthors(authorList);
            myBook.setCopyright("1984");
            myBook.setFormat("paperback");
            myBook.setNumberOfPages(385);
            myBook.setPublishers("Some Publisher");


            System.out.println(myBook);

            Movies myMovie = new Movies();
            myMovie.setTitle("Fargo");
            myMovie.setReleaseDate(2123);
            myMovie.setDirector("Jie Wu");
            myMovie.setActors("Jessie");
            myMovie.setMPAA_rating("R");
            ArrayList<String> actors = new ArrayList<String>();
            actors.add("Tom Hanks");


            System.out.println(myMovie);


            Games myGames = new Games();
            myGames.setTitle("Starcraft");
            myGames.setConsoleType("wii");
            myGames.setEsbnRatings("E");
            myGames.setReleaseDate("2012");
            myGames.setPublishers("Blizzard");

            System.out.println(myGames);
            ArrayList<Media> myMediaList = new ArrayList<Media>();
            myMediaList.add(myBook);
            myMediaList.add(myMovie);
            myMediaList.add(myGame);
            Library myLibrary = new Library();

            for (Media item : myMediaList) {
                myLibrary.addToCollection(item);
                System.out.println(item);
            }


        }

    }

 }
```